# How to remove the items in a list that are in a second list in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sublist

I have a list of lists, and another list, and I want to remove all of the items from the list of lists that are in the second list.

```
first = [[1,3,2,4],[1,2],[3,4,2,5,1]]
to_remove = [1,2]
```

How would I go about doing this problem in general?

There are also similar questions on here but nothing has helped.

Comment: You will need to provide us with the code you tried to use

Comment: Do you want to remove all instances of the items ? If first = [[1,1,3,2,4],[1,2],[3,4,2,5,1]] then is the output different ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An elegant solution using `sets`:

```
first = [[1,3,2,4],[1,2],[3,4,2,5,1]]
to_remove = [1,2]
result = [list(set(x).difference(to_remove)) for x in first]
result
[[3, 4], [], [3, 4, 5]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
result = []
for l in first:
    tmp = []
    for e in l:
        if e not in to_remove:
            tmp.append(e)
    result.append(tmp)

print(result)
```

This code loop over all the list and all the element of each list if the element is in to_remove list it skip it and go to the next.
so if you have multiple intance it will remove it

Best regard

Comment: How could you try this in a *comprehension* style?

Comment: @igorkf yeah sure `result = [[e for e in l if e not in to_remove] for l in first]` :)