# Remove elements of a list of lists with another list

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out how I can eliminate elements of a list of lists using another list.
For example let's suppose I have:

```
eliminate([['dog', 'cat'], ['cat', 'fish'], ['dog', 'hamster]], ['dog', 'cat'])
[[], ['fish'], ['hamster]]
```

I tried iterating through all the elements of the sublists and check if they are in the second list, to have them removed but I am given the same list as the original one.
Any help would be great.

```
def eliminate(ballots, to_eliminate):

    for sublist in ballots:

        for elem in sublist:

            if elem in to_eliminate:
                ballots.pop(sublist.index(elem))
    return ballots
```

Comment: This isn't a homework site and I don't believe it's a coincidence that [someone else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58842091/how-to-remove-the-items-in-a-list-that-are-in-a-second-list-in-python) asked exactly the same thing within a minute of you.  Anyway, you won't learn anything if we give you the answer.

Comment: Can't reproduce "I am given the same list as the original one". For me, your example returns ```[['cat', 'fish']]```. Your problem is that you pop from ```ballot```, not the sublists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If returning a new list is ok

```
def eliminate(ballots, to_eliminate):
    ballots_n = []
    for sublist in ballots:
        temp_list = []
        for elem in sublist:
            if not elem in to_eliminate:
                temp_list.append(elem)
        ballots_n.append(temp_list)
    return ballots_n
```

Answer (score 0):

Learn to use `print` statements to debug your program -- you show no attempt.  For instance:

```
def eliminate(ballots, to_eliminate):

    for sublist in ballots:

        for elem in sublist:

            if elem in to_eliminate:
                print("\nsublist=", sublist, "\telem=", elem)
                print("to_eliminate", to_eliminate)
                print("index", sublist.index(elem))
                ballots.pop(sublist.index(elem))
                print("ballots", ballots)
    return ballots

result = eliminate([['dog', 'cat'], ['cat', 'fish'], ['dog', 'hamster']], ['dog', 'cat'])
print(result)
```

Output:

```
sublist= ['dog', 'cat']     elem= dog
to_eliminate ['dog', 'cat']
index 0
ballots [['cat', 'fish'], ['dog', 'hamster']]

sublist= ['dog', 'cat']     elem= cat
to_eliminate ['dog', 'cat']
index 1
ballots [['cat', 'fish']]
[['cat', 'fish']]
```

This shows your problems quite clearly.

You identify that elimination element `dog` is in one of the sub-lists at position 0 of that sublist.  You handle this by removing `ballots[0]`, rather than the element you identified.  Fix your `pop` reference.

Second, you skip sublists in `ballots`, because you're altering a list as you iterate through it.  Instead, make a new list containing only the elements that you want to keep.  This is a common error in many languages, and is covered by several duplicates here on Stack Overflow.